# NavigationController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation is not getting called if i change the orientation of the topviewcontroller in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c

My  app is navigation based one. I have extended UINavigationController and have implementations of the below methods in NavigationController and individual ViewControllers also.

**-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation**

When the orientation change happens In iOS 7, First Rotation method from Navigation controller gets called then the same method from Actual viewcontroller gets called. I badly need this.

In case of **iOS8** only Rotation method from Viewcontroller gets called not the Navigation controllers one.

Note: I m not using any ios 8 specific orientation method also. As i have change so many things.So please don't suggest me to implement the below - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id )coordinator

Comment: It has been deprecated in iOS8 in favor of `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Answer (score -1):

That method is deprecrated from ios 8

Sent to the view controller before performing a one-step user interface rotation.

```
Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: to make interface-based adjustments.

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Also note that by the time we recevice this notification the view is already change to its new orientation.

For more reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Comment: Question specifically asks _not_ to reference that method. Can you clarify your answer?